# Unable to get the correct syntax for Kill Command Linux inside a ZSH function

Tags: linux, zsh

I am really confused as to what is happening

I copied from one of SO answers a simple function (it's inside my .zshrc)

```
function killport() {
    sudo kill -s STOP $(fuser -n tcp $1 2> /dev/null)
}
```

But when I run it I get

```
$ killport 80  

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
```

I also get the same if I just try to use `` sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8080` `` .

The above mentioned `sudo kill -9` worked for me just yesterday, but today I haven't been able to get it working. Tried adding the `-s` flag for a signal but it should default to `STOP`

Comment: That might happen if there is nothing on that port and fuser didn't return a pid.

Comment: It's a bit optimistic to supply the argument to `kill` using `$(....)` as a parameter. I would first store the result of `fuser` to a variable and test the content of the variable, whether it looks sensible, before doing the `kill`.

Comment: @user1934428 could you formulate an example of how you would approach it in an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Don't use `kill -9`; that's for debugging misbehaving programs. It has no real place in production use.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, turning my comment into an answer:

First calculate the pid to be killed, then test whether the calculation looks reasonable, and then kill the process.

```
pid=$(fuser -n tcp "${1:?parameter missing}" 2>/dev/null)
if [[ -z $pid || $pid == *[^[:digit:]]* ]]
then
  echo "Error: Can not find PID for '$1'" 1>&2
else
  sudo kill -s STOP $pid
fi
```

Comment: Hey, not sure if I am using this incorrectly, but whenever I do `$killport 80` I get that it cannot find PID for port 80 (or whatever port) but when I run `sudo lsof -t -i:80` I do get the PID's. Is the format on the argument of the killport incorrect on my end?

Comment: This means that your way of calculating the pid has a problem. Since this is a new problem, I would ask a new question. Since the problem can be reduced to _how to correctly invoke the `fuser` command_, it is not really a programming problem anymore, and you will perhaps be better served at [su] or [se],

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic : BTW, for debugging, I would first of all turn on `set -x` to make sure that the commands are really issued in the way you expect them - one never knows. Then, I would (also for testing) do the `fuser` command manually, to see what it outputs.